# Inheritance, selective method execution

Tags: c++

I watched a video that can be found at
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc and I really liked some of the concept for the cases that presented.  But I am working with linked list and need selective method execution, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class A {
 public:
    A() : next(0) {
        if (head == 0) {
            head = this;
        } else {
            A* step = head;
            while (step->next != 0) {
                step = step->next;
            }
            step->next = this;
        }
    }
    virtual ~A() {
        if (head == this) {
            head = 0;
        } else {
            A* step = head;
            while (step->next != this) {
                step = step->next;
            }
            step->next = next;
        }
    }
    virtual void foo() {
        // Do nothing...
    }
    static A* head;
    A* next;
};

class B : public A {
 public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}
    virtual void foo() {
        printf("function foo\n");
    }
};

A* A::head = 0;

int main() {
    A a_cls;
    B b_cls;

    A* step = A::head;

    while (step != 0) {
        step->foo();
        step = step->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After instantiating all of the objects, the method `foo()` of objects of class `B` need to execute.  To achieve this, virtual method `foo()` is added to class A, with empty body, `virtual void foo() {}`, and in class B, code is added to the method `foo()` body.

It works but I do not like it, in the main function it looks like you are doing something at each node, but you are not, it almost feels like a NULL pointer.  Is there another creative solution for this?

Note:  I am using C++03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [dynamic_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/#dynamic_cast) as a way to check for a particular derived type and only call `foo` on objects of class `B` (or a class derived from `B`):

```
int main() {
    A a_cls;
    B b_cls;

    A* step = A::head;
    B* step_b = 0;

    while (step != 0) {
        step_b = dynamic_cast<B *>(step);
        if (step_b != 0) {
            step_b->foo();
        }
        step = step->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This way, there's no need to define an empty `foo` method on `A`. Try it out on [ideone](http://ideone.com/RgkTle).

Comment: To the OP: Please understand that this is fragile code. As soon as you introduce type `C` as a sub-type of `A`, you'll need another `if` clause. That's precisely the reason to use polymorphism.

Comment: I think I would need to see more of OP's intent to know whether I agree with this statement. If C derives from B, there's no need for an additional if statement. If we want to call a different method for C than for B, we need an if statement regardless.

Answer (score 0):

> It works but I do not like it, in the `main` function it looks like you are doing something at each node, but you are not, it almost feels like a `NULL` pointer. Is there another creative solution for this?

Make sure that your base class is a pure abstract class. That way, every call to `step->foo();` will most likely do something.

Here's a bare bones example of a heterogeneous list. `List::Node` is an abstract base class. `List::Node::print()` is a virtual member function that is implemented only in the concrete classes. `List` is able to use a generic algorithm to step through the `Node`s without having explicit knowledge of the kinds of `Node`s it contains.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class List
{
   public:

      class Node
      {
         public:
            Node() : next(nullptr) {}
            virtual ~Node() {}
            virtual void print() = 0;
            Node* next;
      };

      List() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}

      ~List()
      {
         Node* node = head;
         Node* next = nullptr;
         for ( ; node != nullptr; node = next )
         {
            next = node->next;
            delete node;
         }
      }

      void addNode(Node* node)
      {
        if (head == 0)
        {
            head = tail = node;
            return;
        }

        if ( head == tail )
        {
           head->next = node;
        }

        tail->next = node;
        tail = node;
      }

      void print()
      {
         Node* node = head;
         for ( ; node != nullptr; node = node->next )
         {
            node->print();
            std::cout << std::endl;
         }
      }

      Node* head;
      Node* tail;
};

class NodeA : public List::Node
{
   public:
      NodeA(int d) : data(d) {}
      virtual ~NodeA() {}
      virtual void print()
      {
         std::cout << "In NodeA::print(), Data: " << data;
      }
   private:
      int data;
};


class NodeB : public List::Node
{
   public:
      NodeB(double d) : data(d) {}
      virtual ~NodeB() {}
      virtual void print()
      {
         std::cout << "In NodeB::print(), Data: " << data;
      }
   private:
      double data;
};


class NodeC : public List::Node
{
   public:
      NodeC(std::string const& d) : data(d) {}
      virtual ~NodeC() {}
      virtual void print()
      {
         std::cout << "In NodeC::print(), Data: " << data;
      }
   private:
      std::string data;
};

int main()
{
   List list;

   list.addNode(new NodeA(10));
   list.addNode(new NodeB(23.45));
   list.addNode(new NodeC("abcd"));

   list.print();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huh? how can this help?  You still need to define every virtual function in every class.  Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @user1135541, not true. You'll need to define them for every concrete classes. If you divide your classes into `List' and `ListNode`, and make `ListNode` a pure virtual class, it will make more sense.

Comment: I like this idea, but I think the answer should be fleshed out a little more to answer the OP's comment. It has to do with intent: what is the real purpose of class A? Is it just to build a list of other objects? If so, it should probably be abstract.

Comment: @AustinMullins, I started down that path but relented since the OP's class `A` is being used both as a list and a node of the list. I'd have to separate those two to be able to present something that will make sense.

Comment: @AustinMullins, I overcame my inertia :)

Comment: I don't really see how this answers the question. OP wants a way to selectively execute a function. This is not selective at all. The only salient difference I see between your code and the OPs is that he provides a default implementation of doing nothing, whereas you force every class to implement. Arguably, your code is further from the goal, because each child class has to do more work to "elide"execution.

Comment: @NirFriedman, the idea of selective execution using `if-else` works OK for couple of classes. As the number classes grow, the code becomes fragile. Use of polymorphic classes avoids that fundamental problem.

Comment: @RSahu I didn't say it had to involve if-else. But your answer is not selective execution. Austin and I both gave solutions that actually selectively execute, and use polymorphism, not if-else.

Comment: @NirFriedman, I don't deny that your answers are good for one `if` check. I am saying that is the right approach to take when you need to have multiple `if-else` checks.

Comment: The OP never said he wants to select between different types of execution, but whether or not something gets executed at all. He was looking for something different than what he has, which was just regular polymorphism. Your answer is very similar to his, but actually slightly worse as he's commented. We all understand typical polymorphism, the difference here is that not all his types meaningfully support one of the pieces of interface.

Answer (score 0):

> It works but I do not like it, in the main function it looks like you
>   are doing something at each node, but you are not

In fact you **are doing something** at each node.  What you are doing is the decision to do nothing.  Decisions are generally not free and you haven't told us enough about the application to justify the guess that it could be restructured in a way that the decision could be effectively free (made at compile time).

If the decision to do nothing can't be free, then implementing that decision as a call to a virtual function is nearly as low in cost as that decision could possibly be.

Comment: The user of the class has to know the contents of the class to know what is going on, so the logic is spread out, with the function being just a `filler` function.  So it is a readability of this that I do not like.

Answer (score 0):

Although Austin's solution is perfectly fine, another approach (that I typically prefer) in such situations is to use interface classes and upcasting.

```
class FooFighter { public: virtual void foo() = 0; };

class A { ... };

class B1 : public A { ... };

class B2 : public A, public FooFighter { ... };

...

int main() {
  std::vector<A *> v;

  // fill up v

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    FooFighter * ff = dynamic_cast<FooFighter *>(v[i]);
    if (ff) ff.foo();
  }
  return 0;
```

}

This lets you keep whether or not a class has foo independent of the rest of your hierarchy. In particular, by examining the class hierarchy of any type you always know whether or not that type implements foo, because it has to inherit from FooFighter. When you use the downcasting approach, you could have multiple children of A that non-trivially implement foo in different ways. This approach also meshes extremely well with IDEs that let you easily examine and traverse the type hierarchies in your code.